# C# WPF DataGridRowDetails

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли сделать RowDetails в DataGrid растягивающимся снизу и как? Или использовать не DataGrid? В какую сторону смотреть?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-add-row- details-to-a-datagrid-control Поищите тут)

Answer (score 0):

[тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/sizing-options-in-the-datagrid-control#resizing-with-the-mouse) как раз описано какие параметры за это отчечают.

А именно:

- [`DataGridColumn.CanUserResize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.canuserresize) - для конкретной колонки
- [`DataGrid.CanUserResizeColumns`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuserresizecolumns) - для всех колонок
- [`DataGrid.CanUserResizeRows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuserresizerows) - для строк

Comment: мне нужно изменять  размер RowDetails, а не строки, я понимаю что оно зависит от размера строки но не могу понять как сделать изменение именно RowDetails